# WordPress - plugin Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, contact-form-7

I use the Contact Form 7 in a WordPress website.

I have this html code generated by another plugin :

```
<div id="modal-contact-form" class="modal" data-created_overlay="true">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <h4 class="bold"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Request to contact', 'mysite' ); ?></h4>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                       class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-flat"><H3><?php echo esc_html__( 'Close', 'mysite' ); ?></h3></a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode( $contact_form ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This pops up the modal form. This works fine !

In the source code I have this within a form-tag :

```
<input type="hidden" id="choice_title" name="choice_title" value="<?php echo $choice_title; ?>" readonly>
```

In WordPress itself ( Contact Form 7 ) in the choosen contact form in the tab "Form" I have :

```
<label> My choice : [text* choice_title id:choice_title] </label>
```

But it is always empty, nothing is filled in the modal form.

I hope an expert "Contact Form 7" can help me to get the value of any field of the form ( because it depends of that input ).

Info : not via using a "get" or "post" submit from before please

Thank you in advance,

Comment: what is  $choice_title and how did you get the value of that hidden input?

Comment: This is done with the plug-in function call get_choice_title() which gives the value as a string ( which I need in my modal form to be send with it )